# How to get the expression for higher order derivatives systematically

Tags: calculus

Given an expression, for example, 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{(x-1)(1-y)(xy+x-1)}$$

How can we find the general expression involving $m$ and $n$ for $$\lim_{x\to 0, y\to 0}{\frac{\partial^{n+m}{f}}{\partial{x}^{m}\partial{y}^{n}}}$$

Comment: Have you considered expanding into power series of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Shai, yes, but how to do it in details? Can you please give the details as well as the final answer?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether you considered that; I haven't thought about the details...

Comment: Why is the final answer so important? Given the method, you could find the answer for this question, as well as for similar ones in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f = \sum_{i,j \geq 0} c_{ij} x^i y^j$. The limit you're looking for is $m!n! c_{mn}$. Your function is better written as $$f(x,y) = \frac{x}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-x-xy)},$$ where the most interesting factor is $$\frac{1}{1-x-xy} = \sum_{t \geq 0} x^t(1 + y)^t = \sum_{t,s \geq 0} \binom{t}{s} x^t y^s.$$ Multiplying by a variable $1/(1-z)$ is like taking "running sums" across $z$. So $$\frac{x}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-x-xy)} = \sum_{t,s \geq 0} x^{t+1} y^s \left[ \sum_{T \leq t, S \leq s} \binom{T}{S} \right]. $$ So the value you're looking for is $$m!n!\sum_{T \leq m-1,S \leq n} \binom{T}{S}.$$